# Unexpected result of rtrim function in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, trim

I'm trying to understand the problem I get with Spark sql function `rtrim`. I'm trying to remove a substring from the string and the result is not as I expected. When I try to remove `_count` from `test_count`, I get `tes` instead of `test`. But if I try to remove `_count` from `TEST_count`, I get `TEST` as expected.

My sample code:

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.rtrim

case class Test(test_count: String, test1_count: String)
val df = Seq(
    Test("test_count", "TEST_count")
).toDF

df
    .withColumn("test", rtrim($"test_count", "_count"))
    .withColumn("test1", rtrim($"test1_count", "_count"))
    .withColumn("test_", rtrim($"test_count", "count"))
    .withColumn("test1_", rtrim($"test1_count", "count"))
    .show
```

Its result:

```
+----------+-----------+----+-----+-----+------+
|test_count|test1_count|test|test1|test_|test1_|
+----------+-----------+----+-----+-----+------+
|test_count| TEST_count| tes| TEST|test_| TEST_|
+----------+-----------+----+-----+-----+------+
```

I was trying to add `\\` before the `_count` but it didn't work. I found the other way to achieve the expected result but I want to understand better how `trim` works in Spark. Am I doing something wrong or the behaviour is indeed unexpected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct behaviour. `rtrim` removes all occurences of the specified **chars** on the right side of the string, NOT the specified string. So if you have `test_count` and you `rtrim` `_count`, it will remove every character in `_`, `c`, `o`, `u`, `n`, `t` starting from the right until it finds a character that is not one of them. This results in the removal of the last `t` in `test`, but not `s` because `s` is not in the list.

```
test_count
   ^^^^^^^ all these are in [`_`, `c`, `o`, `u`, `n`, `t`]
  ^ but this isn't, so the string is trimmed until here
```

To achieve what you wanted, you can use `regexp_replace` to replace the last bit with an empty string. `$` in regex means the end (right side) of the string. If you want to do something similar with `ltrim` you can use `^` in regex.

```
df
    .withColumn("test", regexp_replace($"test_count", "_count$", ""))
    .withColumn("test1", regexp_replace($"test1_count", "_count$", ""))
    .withColumn("test_", regexp_replace($"test_count", "count$", ""))
    .withColumn("test1_", regexp_replace($"test1_count", "count$", ""))
    .show
+----------+-----------+----+-----+-----+------+
|test_count|test1_count|test|test1|test_|test1_|
+----------+-----------+----+-----+-----+------+
|test_count| TEST_count|test| TEST|test_| TEST_|
+----------+-----------+----+-----+-----+------+
```

Comment: Got to know about the working of rtrim function otherwise i was thinking the other way.